# remove rows from excel which have discontinued value in column

Tags: excel, vba

I have columns in my csv like this:

```
Id            Name                     Price
1          Level X discontinued          34
3          Level Y Dicontinued           64
7          Level Z                       94
```

I want to check if in column Name are **discontinued** or **Dicontinued**
If yes delete row, if not, dont do nothing, so my final result will be:

```
Id            Name                     Price
7          Level Z                       94
```

Comment: Apply a filter on name and delete the rows with "discon.."

Comment: What have you researched / tried so far, and what specific problem are you having?

Comment: Showing some effort towards solving your problems would be much appreciated by people on here, see https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score -1, accepted):

A solution can be running the following Excel Macro `ExampleMacro` with the following setup. This code will filter the first worksheet [here `TotalList`] copying the content in a second worksheet [here `Filtered`]

NOTE: please use the same names I used or change the code of the following macro accordingly if you prefer to change the names. Otherwise it will not work

```
Sub ExampleMacro()

Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer
Set ShMaster = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("TotalList")
Set ShSlave = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Filtered")

'cleanup for next macro executions
ShSlave.UsedRange.Clear

'copying the headers
ShSlave.Range("A1").Value = ShMaster.Range("A1").Value
ShSlave.Range("B1").Value = ShMaster.Range("B1").Value
ShSlave.Range("C1").Value = ShMaster.Range("C1").Value

'searching what to keep
j = 2
For i = 2 To ShMaster.UsedRange.Rows.Count
    'MsgBox "value is " & InStr(1, (Range("B" & i).Value), "discontinued")
    If InStr(1, (ShMaster.Range("B" & i).Value), "discontinued") = 0 Then
        While ShSlave.Range("C" & j).Value <> ""
            j = j + 1
        Wend
        ShSlave.Range("A" & j).Value = ShMaster.Range("A" & i).Value
        ShSlave.Range("B" & j).Value = ShMaster.Range("B" & i).Value
        ShSlave.Range("C" & j).Value = ShMaster.Range("C" & i).Value
    End If
Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: @doki today I edited the code to fix a potential situation in which it was not going to behave as expected

Comment: Pls consider more cultural sensitive names when naming your variables.

Comment: @JakobNielsen-MSFT look, master-slave in this answer was nothing more than an usage according to an [established expression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master/slave_(technology)) used in general IT. Can it be changed/improved? Most probably. But in my personal opinion giving -1 because of this to an answer that solves the question originally posted is even more arguable than your observation, misleading readers to think that the code posted doesn't work or is not relevant to the question

Comment: Sorry Antonino, I don't agree with you on that. Please see the concerns about the terminology in the article you linked to and also consider the industry response. I think we can do better when we name things in our work. Especially when here are good alternatives.